# How to express "that's one way to put it" with a hint of understatement?

Tags: выражения

> Тебе не кажется, что этот продукт немного... ну не знаю. Перехваливают что ли?

In conversation, in response to the above, I just said:

> **Пожалуй, это лишь одно из немногих подходящих выражений...** В любом случае, вроде бы он рассматривает это, как вложение в будущее.

Here I wanted to express the idea of "**Well, that's... one way to put it...**" with a hint of understatement -- implying that it could just as well have been described with some other (less pleasant) expressions. I'm not sure if my phrasing sounds idiomatic enough.

What is a commonly used phrasing for this in Russian?

Answer (score 7):

I think this will work well in your situation:

- Это ещё мягко сказано!

Comment: Or simply "Мягко говоря!"

Answer (score 4):

I'd say, "да, можно и так выразиться".
In general, I don't think there are any strongly recommended expressions in this case. Your own phrase is fine, it just sounds too long to me.